# The equivalent behaviour of a HTML block element

Tags: react-native

I'm new to `react-native`, coming from the web-world.

The standard behaviour for a `View` component seem to be to collapse to it's content's width.

Is there a way to have a component always stretch to the full horizontal width, limited only by a parent's fixed width or else screen width?

Any of `width`, `minWidth` or `maxWdith` set to `'100%'` doesn't seem to do any difference.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can simply use the flex box system